# Social-Network Tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I was looking through the tags to see what else might be appropriate to add to a post only tagged with social-network.  The description for that tag reads:

> This tag is appropriate for questions dealing with communities on
>   social networks. It is also appropriate to add more specific tags such
>   as the exact social network being utilized.

So I looked for other social networks to use as tags.  There is one for facebook and another for blog.  There is nothing for websites in general, though there is a web-forums one.  What's a web-forum?  I suppose SE is one...and other bulletin boards.

The question dealt with Twitter and boom, there is no Twitter tag.  No Instagram either.  Is it time to do some updating?

**Can we add a Twitter tag?  Anything else?**

Edited to add:

I wanted to add it to this question: [Establishing yourself in "Regular" and NSFW communities](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/establishing-yourself-in-regular-and-nsfw-communities)

**[Twitter](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=twitter):** While I haven't gone through them all, there are 59 posts on the site that mention the word Twitter. I assume a reasonable percentage of them would benefit from the tag.

**[Instagram](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=instagram)**:  8 posts that mention the word Instagram.

**[Snapchat](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=snapchat)**: 1 snapchat (my teen uses that one a lot so it's just going to get more popular).

**[Wordpress](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=wordpress)**: 19 posts mentioning Wordpress. These can go under "blog" but talking about the general care and feeding of a blog is very different from talking about technical issues regarding the software. I'd recommend both tags.

Comment: Can you provide a list of posts that would need `Twitter`? We can add a tag, but if we don't get it on a post in 24 hours, it clears itself out. Any other ones you had in mind?

Comment: I wanted to add it to this question: https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/establishing-yourself-in-regular-and-nsfw-communities

Comment: While I haven't gone through them all, there are 59 posts on the site that mention the word Twitter.  I assume a reasonable percentage of them would benefit from the tag.  https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=twitter

Comment: 8 posts that mention the word Instagram: https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=instagram

Comment: 1 snapchat (my teen uses that one a lot so it's just going to get more popular).  https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=snapchat

Comment: 19 posts mentioning Wordpress.  These can go under "blog" but talking about the general care and feeding of a blog is very different from talking about technical issues regarding the software.  I'd recommend both tags.  https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=wordpress

Comment: @Andy Sorry to flood the comments here.  I can create answers for each suggested tag so they get voted on, or edit the original question, just let me know.  I also don't know if I, with my low rep, can create any of these tags myself (subject to approval from moderators).  Not to be badge hunting but well... :-)

Comment: Can you add the comments to the question (as an edit). That'll make it a little easier for us to vote on. I'm pretty sure you can add tags. It looks to me a [150 rep](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege. Congratulations! :)

Comment: We do have a few additional platforms (not necessarily social-media) too. [reddit](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reddit) [stack-exchange](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) and [irc](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irc) are ones that popped out when I quickly skimmed the tags.

Comment: @Andy I've done the edit.  IRC lol!  I love that service and used it extensively...in the 1990's.  Might be time for some updating.

Comment: @Andy and others...so will there be voting?  Any one else care to weigh in?  Should I just create a couple tags and see if there is protest?  Do I need to make a temp post to create them, then retag some other posts with the new tags, and remove my post?

Comment: Go ahead and create them. You should be able to add the tag to a post without creating a temporary post.

Comment: @Andy I appear to have successfully created a Twitter tag by editing the post I link to in the question.  Although I have enough rep to create tags, that appears to be on my own posts only.  I do not have enough rep to edit and need to get approval for each one.  I also had to edit at least 6 characters in the body of the post to get the edit request to go through; fortunately, the OP modified the post and I found a couple typos to fix.  Once it's approved, I am willing to add the tag to all relevant posts, but that will create a long editing approval queue.  How do you want me to handle it?

Comment: the mobile app doesn't seem to have posted my comment yesterday. The edit has been approved. Also, I'll be off of mobile after the first of the year and can help out more effectively when I'm on a more stable connection.

Comment: @Andy I did see the approval, thanks.  My question is do you want me to do the work of adding this and other tags to maybe 100 more questions, or will that create a nightmare for you and others since I don't have the rep to edit questions without them going into a queue for others to approve?

Comment: Let's create an answer below with a list of each post that gets Twitter tags. With that many we'd flood the home page with old edits. We may be able to get a community manager involved to mass retag, but we'll need a metal post with an answer detailing it. Instagram and Snapchat can be added by us without any issues.

Comment: @Andy Turns out I was wrong about the numbers.  The search brings up answers in addition to questions.  So there are only 8 questions that would clearly benefit from a twitter tag (in addition to the 1 I already tagged) and 3 maybes.  Should I go ahead and retag them?

Answer (score 1):

**Posts that would benefit from the Twitter tag:**

I created the tag on this post, which has been approved:
[Establishing yourself in "Regular" and NSFW communities](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/establishing-yourself-in-regular-and-nsfw-communities)

There are [59 posts containing the word "twitter."](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=twitter)  I assumed these were questions but it turns out answers are counted here as well.  So there are not as many questions as I thought.

These are the ones I would like to add the new twitter tag to.

- [What's going on with Twitter following limit per day?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/whats-going-on-with-twitter-following-limit-per-day)
- [How should a tech company communicate on Twitter?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/how-should-a-tech-company-communicate-on-twitter)
- [Cross posting to Twitter, Facebook, etc. for more exposure and growth](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/774/cross-posting-to-twitter-facebook-etc-for-more-exposure-and-growth)
- [Strategies for keeping multiple platforms in sync?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/strategies-for-keeping-multiple-platforms-in-sync)
- [Define strategy to social networks targeting multiple countries](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/define-strategy-to-social-networks-targeting-multiple-countries)
- [Steal Hashtags in social networks as guerrilla strategy](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/steal-hashtags-in-social-networks-as-guerrilla-strategy)
- [Create a community in a twitch lifestream](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/create-a-community-in-a-twitch-lifestream)
- [Is superfluous content an indicator of anything in social media?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/is-superfluous-content-an-indicator-of-anything-in-social-media)

**Posts that maybe should have a twitter tag:**

- [How can I deal with a user harassing me off-site?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/271/how-can-i-deal-with-a-user-harassing-me-off-site)
- [Ways to notify interested autistic contacts of next meetings](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/ways-to-notify-interested-autistic-contacts-of-next-meetings)
- [Determine where my traffic is coming from?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/determine-where-my-traffic-is-coming-from)

**Posts I don't think need a twitter tag:**

- [new community - How to build the audience little by little](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/new-community-how-to-build-the-audience-little-by-little)
- [What to do when a child contacts you?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/982/what-to-do-when-a-child-contacts-you)
- [Increasing Engagement on a new Gaming Blog](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/increasing-engagement-on-a-new-gaming-blog)
- [Build a "liking" feature that best fosters an active community](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/build-a-liking-feature-that-best-fosters-an-active-community)
- [Invoking the Streisand Effect - A personal response?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/invoking-the-streisand-effect-a-personal-response)
- [How to leverage reputation systems of other communities to encourage participation in your own](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/how-to-leverage-reputation-systems-of-other-communities-to-encourage-participati)

Answer (score 1):

**Snapchat Tag**

https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=snapchat

There is only one mention of Snapchat and it's in an answer.  So there is no need for a tag at this time.

I will say though that when I asked my teen (an expert! aren't they all?) about this issue and which social media platforms might need tags, she was adamant that Snapchat be included.  Because teens use it a lot.  Which means that 10 years from now, it will be part of the adult community.

But until we get a post that talks about it, I say let's hold off on the tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Wordpress Tag**

Of the [19 mentions of Wordpress on the site](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=wordpress), 7 are questions.

I created the tag using this post: [Wordpress comments vs Forum](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/wordpress-comments-vs-forum)

**I would also like to add the wordpress tag to these questions:**

- [Wordpress Anti-spam measures?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/968/wordpress-anti-spam-measures)
- [Strategies for keeping multiple platforms in sync?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/strategies-for-keeping-multiple-platforms-in-sync)
- [Increasing Engagement on a new Gaming Blog](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/increasing-engagement-on-a-new-gaming-blog)
- [Embedded comments on a blog - in place commenting vs dedicated forum](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/embedded-comments-on-a-blog-in-place-commenting-vs-dedicated-forum)

**I do not feel a wordpress tag is needed for these posts:**

- [How can I promote my Mumford and Sons Fan Group?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/how-can-i-promote-my-mumford-and-sons-fan-group)
- [What is the expiration date for featured content?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/what-is-the-expiration-date-for-featured-content)

Comment: I feel several of those posts are off-topic here and should be on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Youtube Tag**

There are [15 mentions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=youtube) of youtube.

I created a [youtube](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) tag for this question: [Strategies for keeping multiple platforms in sync?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/strategies-for-keeping-multiple-platforms-in-sync)

I went ahead and created the tag because I was already editing the above question to add existing tags to it and it made sense to do it all together.

None of the other questions mentioning Youtube are asking anything that has to do with Youtube specifically.

If this is too specific a tag, reject it. But Youtube is a legitimate community where people have discussions (in comments) about videos posted there, and there are tech issues with posting, syncing, etc.  So I expect to see more questions about it.

[video-sites](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-sites) or [video-social-network](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-social-network) might be another option, with synonyms for  [youtube](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) and [vine](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vine) and whatever else might pop up.

Answer (score -1):

**Instagram Tag**

https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=instagram

I created the instagram tag by editing
[Ideas on how to create interest/community for a photography website?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/ideas-on-how-to-create-interest-community-for-a-photography-website)

The other question mentioning Instagram does not appear to need a tag.
[Build a "liking" feature that best fosters an active community](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/build-a-liking-feature-that-best-fosters-an-active-community)

Comment: The instagram under that post is irrelevant; the OP *mentions* several social media sites, but the question *is about* a private site.

Comment: It's asking about promotion and Instagram is one of the platforms they're using for promotion.  Facebook would be another.  It's borderline but I believe it falls on the "add the tag" side of the line.